# Proof on Rational Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am trying to determine whether the following structure forms a Ring under the Real Number Definition of Addition and Multiplication

Consider the set of Real Numbers of the form:

$A = \{a + bp \:|\: a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, p \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}\}$ 
with $p$ being fixed.

And consider the structure $\left(A, +, .\right)$

Where + and . are as defined in the Real Numbers.

It's fairly easy to show that axioms over addition are satisfied and that it forms an Albelian Group.

For multiplication however I don't believe that it's closed.

Taking two elements in $A$ say

$x_{1} = a_{1} + b_{1}p$ and $x_{2} = a_{2} + b_{2}p$

Then

$x_{1} \cdot x_{2} = \left(a_{1}a_{2} + b_{1}b_{2}p^{2}\right) + \left(a_{1}b_{2} + a_{2}b_{1}\right)p$

Now unless I'm interpreting this incorrectly I can only say that it is of the form of A : $x = a + bp \iff p^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$

If $p^{2} \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$

Then $x$ now takes the form

$x = a + bp_{1} + cp_{2}$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $p_{1}, p_{2} \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ and $p_{1} \neq p_{2}$

As such I can not conclude that the set A is closed under multiplication unless $p^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Have I missed something here?

Thanks, David

Comment: Sounds OK to me.  For example if $p={\root3\of2}$ then $A$ is not a ring.

Comment: Is $p$ a fixed irrational number, i.e. common for all elements of $A$? Your notation suggests it is not.

Comment: I was initially working with $p = \sqrt{q}$ where $q$ is a non zero and non square Natural Number. In that case then yes multiplication is closed (and satisfies all axioms to form a ring). I was extending to to any irrational number $p$.

Comment: @posilon - Yes it is fixed. I should have declared that. I have now corrected. Cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't missed anything. To be closed under multiplication $p$ should necessarily  be a root of a quadratic equation with rational coefficients. (It is called an algebraic number of degree 2).

Comment: Cheers mate. I was first only thinking Natural Non Square Number as being those that satisfy but didn't know it extending as you have defined. Still new to Abstract Algebra.
Thanks again.